# how to clear input helper after action is handled?

Tags: ember.js

I'm using Ember v 1.13.8

I have input helper:

```
{{input type="text" value=newData action="addNewItem"}}
```

and action handler:

```
actions: {
    addNewItem: function(value) {
      this.get('personList').pushObject({name: value});
      this.set('newData', '');
    }
}
```

As you can see in order to clear input I have variable in controller where I store temporary value. I made `input` helper dependent on it and this approach works, but I wonder may be there is Ember way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach is correct. The only more Ember way I can see is using new JavaScript syntax when declaring function:

```
actions: {
    addNewItem(value) {
      this.get('personList').pushObject({name: value});
      this.set('newData', '');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason to set it to `null` instead?